# Powershell script Cannot bind argument to parameter 'String' because it is null

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I am switching user in powershell script

```
# password is secret variable from azure devops pipeline 
$username = 'user2'
$password = convertto-securestring $env:password -AsPlainText -Force
```

Note: it work for normal string and it wont work for secure variable string

I am getting below error:

```
ConvertTo-SecureString : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'String' because it is null.
At D:\azdo\_work\_temp\cb1ff41e-8df7-48b7-bc48-f23f47d47b8a.ps1:9 char:36
+ $password = convertto-securestring $env:password -AsPlainText ...
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [ConvertTo-SecureString], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToSe 
   cureStringCommand
```

Comment: There is actually no environment variable named `ansible_password` in your context and then, it's evaluated as `$null`

Comment: @Cid, update variable in error, but it is failing for secure variable and normal string it is working

Comment: What happens if you explicitly set the environment password: `$env:password = 'MyPassword'`?

Comment: @sagar same comment applies with the corrected name : there is no env variable named `password`, that's why it's null

Comment: @Iron its in that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure DevOps YAML pipelines you need to explicitly map the secret variables to make them available in scripts (this is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables)):

```yaml
- powershell: |
    Write-Host "Using the mapped env var for this task works and is recommended: $env:MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR"
  env:
    MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR: $(mySecret) # the recommended way to map to an env variable
```